# Next card delay is working on iPad but not on Max

Tags: livecode

I have 2 cards and input command "go to next card" and "go to prev card" with effect.

The first card code on button:

```
on mouseUp
    visual effect push left very fast
    go to next card 
end mouseUp
```

And the second card code on button:

```
on mouseUp
   visual effect push right very fast
   go to prev card
end mouseUp
```

It's delay is 2 seconds. I have tested it on iPad which works, but on Mac there is no delay.

I use livecode version 6.7(dp4) on macOS.

What's happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a retina iPad? There can be delays with visual effects when the screen resolution is high. I have the same issue on a high-resolution Android tablet. The delay is about the same as yours, 2 seconds. I did not see the same delay when I built the app with LC 5.x, it was introduced in the 6.x version because of new image caching features.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this with LiveCOde 6.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8. Your code is correct and it works fine.

You don't write which version of Mac OS X you're using. Perhaps, this visual effect doesn't work correctly on your version of Mac OS X. Also, I have QuickTime 7.6.6 installed. If you have a different version of QT, this may be the culprit.

Perhaps your Mac is just too fast to show "very fast" visual effects. In this case, I would report it to RunRev as a bug and they might make a some small adjustment to make it work on your Mac and your version of OSX.

It is also possible that there is a bug in LiveCode 7, which makes the syntax dysfunctional. You may try this:

```
on mouseUp
    lock screen for visual effect
    go to next card 
    unlock screen with visual effect push left very fast
end mouseUp
```

When I read the LiveCode dictionary, I notice that most visual effects are listed together with the platform on which they work. There is no platform listed for the push effect. Perhaps there is a known problem that makes it not work on some versions of Mac OS X.

Either way, this is probably a bug and you might report it as such, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for answer.But,In this case I test on iPad.It's delay.But on Mac.It's not delay.

Comment: What is the problem with that delay exactly? You only write that there is a delay, not why it is wrong. I thought the delay is as it should be?